# Javascrippt not redirecting user after validation of username

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>

    <script>
        function myFun(){

            var correct_way = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

            var a = document.getElementById("User_Name").value;

            if(a=="") {
                document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username.";
                return false;
            }
            if(a.length<5){
                document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username with 5 or more characters";
                return false;
            }
            if(a.match(correct_way))
                document.location.href = "test1.html";
                else{
                document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username with only letters and integers";
                return false;
            }


        }
    </script>

    <form onsubmit="return myFun()">
    <input type="text" id="User_Name" value=""></input>
    <br></br>
    <span id="Message">  </span> 
    <br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Hello, I have created a username validation code. The validation does work however, the user is not redirected to the 'test1.html' document. They are both in the same folder. How do i make it redirect after the validation is checked?

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should return `true` at the end of function `myFun`.

HTML

```
<form action="test1.html" onsubmit="return myFun()">
<input type="text" id="User_Name" value="" />
<span id="Message">  </span> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Updated code

```
function myFun(){
        var correct_way = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

        var a = document.getElementById("User_Name").value;

        if(a=="") {
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username.";
            return false;
        }
        if(a.length<5){
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username with 5 or more characters";
            return false;
        }
        if(a.match(correct_way)){
              alert("Sucessful Login, welcome to BREAKOUT!");

        }
            else{
            document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML="Please enter a username with only letters and integers";
            return false;
        }

    return true;    
    }
```

jsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h67q09mp/

Comment: thanks! one more thing. I would like to put alerts instead of the document Get element by id messages. I tried putting alert.("Sucessful Login, welcome to BREAKOUT!"); however, the alert does not appear.

Comment: Where did you put the alert. Replace this line `document.location.href = "test1.html";` with alert box. I have created an jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u75w2r6s/

Comment: So, I have put the alert in the if(a.match(correct_way)) statement. Basically, when the username is validated a alert box should say "Successful Login, welcome to BREAKOUT!" and redirect the user to test1.html

Comment: It does not appear!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look Here is jsFiddle with your code - http://jsfiddle.net/h67q09mp/